# "Delete" key position on android

Tags: android, position, delete, keypad

I wonder why the "delete" key is now located on the top part of the keypad screen. I can see that both for iOS and Android. I remember that few month (or years maybe…) ago, this was more often located on the bottom of the screen, near the call icon.

I'm today working on a keypad design for an Android App. I'm not sure I get the value of having this "delete" button near the numbers I'm typing. I think it is more obvious to have that "delete" button on the bottom part. The top version seems really far away to tap on. I know it depends of the device we use, but I can feel that on my Nexus 5.

Attached, the native Android Kitkat keypad display with top located delete button, vs Viber app, with the key displayed on the bottom.

Have you ever experienced that? Any though?

[image: Native Keypad Android OS]
[image: Viber app for Android]

Comment: I don't know the answer why. But for me, having the delete key at the top next to my input makes it easy for me to see where I made a mistake and what needs deleting. It does remove the functionality for "clear all" though, which can make it slower if I can have repeatedly hit delete or press and hold to select all before I delete. I'm not sure how often I'll need to start over from scratch when it comes to entering in a phone number.

Comment: It's been a long time I didn't see that "clear all" button. Since the text here is not really long, it's not a problem for me the tap several times to delete the whole numbers.
Concerning the position of the "delete" key, I don't know why but it feels instinctive to have it on the bottom. I prefer for my thumb positioning. Less effort, and I'm still in the flow of typing. No need to make a break by going on the top part.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has a lot to do with giving context to action items. In the case of the delete button, both iOS and Android are using the [UI Principle of Proximity](http://books.google.ca/books?id=Q3Xp_Awu49sC&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=proximity%20user%20interface%20guideline&source=bl&ots=IZb5DY7kZ3&sig=3FK6g4RWmJ74f_RJe56yhNAeHrU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FKlXU9D7MaO-2gWP4oEo&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=proximity%20user%20interface%20guideline&f=false) to heighten the importance of the button.

Additionally, having the delete button placed next to the number field allows for less visual competition at the bottom of the screen. The main action here is to enter numbers, not delete them. As such, the content is responding adequately to the immediate needs of the user.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: "having the button placed next to the button allows for less visual competition at the bottom of the screen"
Not sure I get that :) Which button are you talking about? Thanks for the help

Comment: Whoops! My bad, edited post :)